# Hover effect not responding in css

Tags: html, css, hover

Hello can someone help me with hover effect in `.todo-button:hover`
I tried a lot of versions but nothing seems to work i mean zero response from a browser :(
There must be some mistake in `.todo-button` construction it seems

```css
* {
  box-sizing: flex-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: "Trebuchet MS", "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Grande", "Lucida Sans", Arial, sans-serif;
}

.todo-button {
  width: 100px;
  padding: 16px;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 0 4px 4px 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: none;
  background: linear-gradient( 90deg, rgba(93, 12, 255, 1) 0%, rgba(155, 0, 250, 1) 100%);
  color: #fff;
  text-transform: capitalize;
}

.todo-button:hover {
  background-color: #3e8e41;
}
```

Comment: Please provide a minimal reproduciable code snippet (ctrl + m) showing the sisue directly in the question. Cutting it down to **minimal** is also the first step to pin-point the issue for debugging.

Answer (score 2):

In your class you use property `background` which overwrites the property `background-color` even it is used in a hover class. Just change hover class to:

```
.todo-button:hover {
  background: #3e8e41;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

plz try this code

```css
* {
  box-sizing: flex-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: "Trebuchet MS", "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Grande", "Lucida Sans", Arial, sans-serif;
}

.todo-button {
  width: 100px;
  padding: 16px;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 0 4px 4px 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: none;
  background: linear-gradient( 90deg, rgba(93, 12, 255, 1) 0%, rgba(155, 0, 250, 1) 100%);
  color: #fff;
  text-transform: capitalize;
}


.todo-button:hover
{
    background: #3e8e41;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <style>
        
    </style>
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <button name="btn" class="todo-button">submit

    </button>
</body>
</html>
```